# Android: Read Image (Jpeg) and show on ImageView, Performance Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, jpeg, bufferedreader

I have successfully try to read and show jpeg image on my android phone from PC. I use TCP connection, with client socket on android phone.
I have performance issues in FHD and Quality 20 streaming.

The main reasons are:

1. The read from stream that causes 70-150ms delay (*SOLVED)
2. The decoding to Bitmap that cause the same delay (still remains...)

*before image send, I write image size so I know exactly my buffer size

***Here is some code from my implementation;***
                 *UPDATED*

```
ins = new DataInputStream(imgSocket.getInputStream());
//outImg BufferedWriter
//inImg BufferedReader 
@Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && previewState)
            {
                int size = Integer.valueOf(inImg.readLine());
                outImg.write("Ok", 0, 2);
                outImg.flush();

                byte[] imgBuff = new byte[size];
                ins.readFully(imgBuff, 0, imgBuff.length);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBuff, 0, imgBuff.length, options);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                });

                outImg.write("sendFrame");
                outImg.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also want to ask if its possible to decode jpeg from accelerated hardware.

- I've check [SKIA](https://skia.org/user/quick/android) library. Is a preferable sollution?
- I read about [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) but it seems not to support jpeg decode.

Is there any suggestion about these performance issues?

Comment: in your case the read from stream delay depends on your image size, since you are reading it all once

Comment: I solved it with readFully from DataIputStream. Thanks for your notice!